# What are the resource requirements for x number of users to connect and run code through an RStudio Server instance?

Tags: remote-access, linode, resources

I recently deployed a Centos7 server through Linode and installed RStudio Server. I've created a small teaching exercise and I'd like to have 15 - 20 students connect and run some code. I have two questions:

(1) Are there some guidelines for the needed resources (RAM, number of CPU cores, etc.) based on number of users? For example, 1GB of RAM per user or 1 CPU core for every four users - something like that?

(2) Is there a way for me to test this on my own by simulating 20 users running the code at the the same time?

I would typically tackle this through a trial and error approach, but that is not an option here because I have to get this right on the first try! Obviously, too much horsepower is way better than not enough, but I also want to keep costs down as much as possible. However, I can keep the server powered off and only boot up at necessary times since Linode uses an hourly billing system.

---

For context, the code that needs to run is not terribly complex (50 lines that run some statistical tests, generates some maps, etc.). I've created users already, and I'm able to run a couple instances simultaneously without any problems. I'm currently using the Linode 4GB plan which has:

- 4     GB RAM
- 2     CPU Cores
- 48    GB SSD Storage
- 3     TB Transfer
- 40    Gbps Network In
- 1000  Mbps Network Out

Comment: How big is the dataset? That's roughly 175mb per user after OS overhead for RAM

Comment: @nijave The dataset is pretty small: 1.6mb